# Why should we use the name attribute with the value "s" in the creation of the search form?

Tags: search, forms

I was doing a search form when I realized that if I change the value of the name attribute to something other than "s", the search.php page will not be displayed.

How can I change and still display the search.php page?

**NOTE:** I used the translator if there are any errors. I ask you to please edit for me and sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Welcome to the site. The `s` input name in the form, will become a GET parameter, if the form's method is set to GET and WordPress will treat it as a search query. I wonder why you need to change it?

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute of the input element becomes the query parameter in the URL when the form is submitted. So for an input with the name `s` the URL will look like:

```
http://example.com/?s=my+search+query
```

WordPress is built so that the `s` parameter indicates a search, so it then queries based on that value and loads the search.php template.

There isn't a way to change the name of the query parameter used for search per se, but you could use an early hook to manually set the value of `$_GET['s']` to the value of your own parameter name.

For example, if you wanted to use `q` as the input name:

```
function wpse_324429_search_parameter() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
        $_GET['s'] = $_GET['q'];
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_324429_search_parameter' );
```

Manually setting a value in `$_GET` *feels* wrong to me, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.